# remove part of string after substring

Tags: php

This may be a dupe, but I cannot seem to find a thread which matches this issue. I want to remove all chars from a string *after* a given sub-string - but the chars and the number of chars after the sub-string is unknown. Most solutions I have found seem to only work for removing the given sub-string itself or a fixed length after a given sub-string.

I have

```
$str = preg_replace('(.gif*)','.gif$',$str);
```

Which locates 'blahblah.gif?12345' ok, but I cannot seem to remove the chars after the sub-string '.gif'. I read that $ denotes EOS so I thought this would work, but apparently not. I also tried

```
'.gif$/'
```

and simply

```
'.gif'
```

Comment: Are you only dealing with URLs? Is the sole purpose of this to remove query parameters? If this is the case there are [easier (non-regex) methods that you can use.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Comment: I'm dealing with images, so if I used parse_url would www.page.com/image.gif?123 not simply return www.page.com?

Comment: Actually, no. It'll return exactly what you are looking for - the URL without the query string (everything after the `?` character).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done without regex:

```
echo substr('blahblah.gif?12345', strpos('blahblah.gif?12345', '.gif') + 4);
// returns ?12345                    this is the length of the substring ^
```

So the code is:

```
$str = 'original string';
$match = 'matching string';
$output = substr($str, strpos($str, $match) + strlen($match));
```

---

Ok, now I'm not sure if you want to keep the first or the second part of the string. Anyway, here's the code for keeping the first part:

```
echo substr('blahblah.gif?12345', 0, strpos('blahblah.gif?12345', '.gif') + 4);
// returns blahblah.gif           ^ this is the key
```

And the full code:

```
$str = 'original string';
$match = 'matching string';
$output = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, $match) + strlen($match));
```

---

See the both examples work here: http://ideone.com/Ge30rY

Comment: +1 for effort alone. The examples you gave helped immensely, thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, you're welcome. I'll try reading questions more carefully in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (from [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999114/remove-part-of-string-after-substring?noredirect=1#comment38868715_24999114)) that you are working with actual URLs as your source string, I believe that the best course of action here would be to use PHP's built-in functionality for working with and parsing URLs. You do this by using the [`parse_url()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

> (PHP 4, PHP 5)
>   **`parse_url`** — Parse a URL and return its components
>
> This function parses a URL and returns an associative array containing any of the various components of the URL that are present.
>
> This function is not meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it up into the above listed parts. **Partial URLs are also accepted**, `parse_url()` tries its best to parse them correctly.

From your example: `www.page.com/image.gif?123` (or even just `image.gif?123`) using `parse_url()` will look something like this:

```
var_dump( parse_url( "www.page.com/image.gif?123" ) );

array(2) {
  ["path"]=>
  string(22) "www.page.com/image.gif"
  ["query"]=>
  string(3) "123"
}
```

As you can see, without the need for regular expressions or string manipulations we have broken up the URL into it's separate components. No need to re-invent the wheel. Nice and clean :)

Comment: That indeed is a good clean implementation. I will remember that in future, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$str = "somecontent.gif?anddata";
$pattern = ".gif";
echo strstr($str,$pattern,true).$pattern;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set up string to search through
$haystack = "blahblah.gif?12345";

// Determine substring and length of it
$needle = ".gif";
$length = strlen($needle);

// Find position of last substring
$location = strrpos($haystack, $needle);

// Use location of last occurence + it's length to get new string
$newtext = substr($haystack, 0, $location+$length);
```